# How to download the Firewall in Kali?

Tags: firewall, kali-linux

I tried the following :

1. I updated the source list
2. updated and upgraded using

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. used the command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gufw
   ```
4. and when I type in `gufw` This error appears:

   ```
   bash: gufw: command not found
   ```

And when I run

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

I get this error :

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like the package manager's got into an inconsistent state. Have you tried doing as the second error suggests and running `sudo apt-get -f install` followed by trying `sudo apt-get install gufw` again?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: OK, well, we're going to need a little more information.  Does the `sudo apt-get -f install` have any output at all?  Does the error message change? How about combining them into `sudo apt-get -f install gufw`? Also, crucially, was there any more information about what dependencies couldn't be installed that you omitted from the output of `sudo apt-get install gufw`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to install a "firewall" to kali, just install `ufw`, not `gufw`. `ufw` is easy to use anyways.

Also, I strongly recommend you to NOT use kali as a daily OS as it's an OS designed for pentesting and not for daily use, especially due to the default profile being root and the security level not being that high.

---

That being said, to install `ufw`:

Just open a terminal prompt, do `sudo apt-get update` and then run

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

---

To enable ufw, run:

```
ufw enable
```

---

To open a port with ufw, you can run:

```
ufw allow <port>
```

To close a port with ufw, you can run either

```
ufw deny <port>
```

or

```
ufw reject <port>
```

---

To change the default behavior in `ufw`, run:

```
ufw default allow/deny/reject
```

This is the rule that applies to all ports that you didn't open or close with `ufw allow/deny/reject <port>`.